# Solution for submitting fillable pdf with signature on mobile devices?

Tags: html, pdf, forms, submission

I have been experimenting with PDF forms in Acrobat and LiveCycle.  I was able to create a fillable PDF that can be flattened and emailed from a mobile device using the Adobe Acrobat mobile app.

I am hoping to come up with a better solution, where given a fillable pdf form, the form can be populated and submitted (preferably via http post). Unfortunately this does not seem to be a straightforward task on mobile devices.  Is my best bet to just try and recreate the form using HTML instead?

Comment: What is wrong with the current solution you have, "flattened and emailed"? When you say "signature" you mean a visual signature, or a full cryptographic digital signature?

Comment: The current solution requires a third party app on mobile devices.  We are also hoping to insert the populated info into a database.  Visual signature would be sufficient.

Comment: So you don't want to use any third party apps, but can you use any 3rd party SDK/libraries that you integrate into your own app? Also, what mobile platforms are you targeting? Is your current app web based or native? What frameworks do you currently, or want to, use?

Comment: @Ryan I guess there isn't a strict requirement against 3rd party apps/sdks/libraries.  We currently support iOS and Android, but use CodenameOne as a WORA solution. Right now our users are manually populating a PDF form, so we were hoping to streamline that as much as possible by using a fillable form that can be submitted with ease.  Essentially hoping for the same experience an HTML Form with submit button would provide, while utilizing a pre-existing PDF form.